# How to refresh a route's resolved data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-router

Consider the following route configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
    resolve: {
      app: AppResolver
    },
    children: [
      {
        path: 'user/:uid',
        resolve: {
          user: UserResolver
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: ViewUserComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'edit',
            component: EditUserComponent
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

The user data are retrieved by `UserResolver` for any children of route `/user/:uid`.
Using this data, a user profile can be viewed by navigating to `/user/:uid` and then edited by navigating to `/user/:uid/edit`.
Upon a successful edit, one would expect to be redirected to the user's **updated** profile (`/user/:uid`).

However, both the view and edit page being children of the resolved route, the resolver is not triggered when navigating from one to the other.

Consequently, when navigating back from the edit component to the view component, the data displayed is still the old, non-updated one.

Would there be any way to invalidate the resolved `user` data to force the resolver to fetch it again from the server? Or is there any other way to achieve that kind of result?

The `app` data being unchanged, we shouldn't have to reload it.

Comment: Use shared service instead of parent component for handling data.

Comment: @HarryNinh I could, but it would mean duplicating the code subscribing to the route param and calling the service in every children component while re-implementing a caching strategy in the shared service. This seems to defeat the purpose of the route resolvers.

Comment: Lots and lots of searching on the subject. As best as I can tell the only way to handle this is to subscribe to an event and reload the data manually. Ideally, you'd structure the app. so that you can do that through code reuse, but even that is a challenge because reusing a Resolve is not trivial on account of getting the router state. I've opted to create a public function within my Resolve that can be reused and bypass the resolve function itself. This is a definite area where there could be improvement. I've seen lots of people having this sort of issue.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've tested the solution 'runGuardsAndResolvers', it works for my use case, the resolver is called at each sub-page changes.

It is only adding this option the part of your routes that you want behave this way.

```
export const ROUTES: any = [
  {
    path: 'project/:name',
    runGuardsAndResolvers: "always",
    component: ProjectComponent,
    resolve: { project: ProjectResolver },
    children: [
      ...
```

Comment: In a lot of use cases this is as easy as configuration fix! Neat! Exacly whaat I was looking for... @vlaurin:  This anwswer should be marked as the answer ?

Comment: Is there any way to use runGuardsAndResolvers on the child route? i tried adding this, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 9):

There is a parameter you can use in your route configuration called 'runGuardsAndResolvers' that will affect when the resolver runs. In this case you would want to set it to 'always'. This means that the resolver will run any time the child routes of that route change. See [the route documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Routes) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.activatedRoute.parent.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.profile = data.profile;
  });
}

updateProfile(newProfile) {
  (this.activatedRoute.parent.data as BehaviorSubject<any>).next({profile: newProfile});
}
```

Comment: I just wanted to update the data without changing the URL. This really worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

By above way i can call the resolver. But it not change data which comes from my backend server so i got one solution i call my service method again in success part  and got new changed data from backend server.